# Access keys and vals in listed python-dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got a list k with the 0'th element:

```
k[0]: {'pattern': 0, 'pos': array([   9.83698,  106.539  ,  130.314  ]), 'id': 1922}
```

(It looks like a dict, but its a list indeed)
when I iterate through the 0'th element of the list k and print out each element I Get:

```
for i in k:
    print i
```

=>output:

```
pattern
pos
id
```

I'd like to access not only the keys but the values as well. How to do this?
I've also tried to convert the list back into a dict using zip and izip, but same resutlts...i.e. only keys are printed, no values...
any help will be appreciated

thx in advance

Comment: It looks like a dict because it really is a dict, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use k.values() to iterate through the values, or k.items() to iterate through (key, value) pairs

```
for value in k.values():
     print value

for key, value in k.items():
     print key, value
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to iterate over the dictionary you created (it is in fact a dictionary) is **not** to create the lists of keys/values using `k[0].keys()`, `k[0].values` and `k[0].items()` but using `k[0].iteritems()` which creates a dictionary iterator that returns just the pairs without allocating lists in the memory.

It also runs much faster for big dictionaries (`a` being the dictionary):

```
>>> non_iter_timer = timeit.Timer("for k,v in a.items(): k + v", setup="a = {x:x for x in xrange(10000000)}")
>>> non_iter_timer.repeat(3, 10)
[25.612606023166585, 25.100741935717622, 24.840450306339463]

>>> iter_timer = timeit.Timer("for k,v in a.iteritems(): k + v", setup="a = {x:x for x in xrange(10000000)}")
>>> iter_timer.repeat(3, 10)
[9.26259596885518, 9.198298194571748, 9.77466250122282]
```